# How do limits work on solutions of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Can we compare the solutions of differential equations by taking limits with respect to a parameter?

For example, consider the following second-order ordinary linear differential equation:

$$y''(x) + b  y(x)' = 1$$

The solution will be an affine surface parametrized by $c_1$ and $c_2$, where given some initial conditions we can identify the unique solution:

$$y_{b}(x) = c_1 \frac{e^{-bx}}{b}+\frac{x}{b}+c_2$$

Now, if $b=0$, then the solution will be (parametrizing the affine space by $k_1$ and $k_2$):

$$y_{b=0}(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}+k_1x+k_2$$

I have two questions:

1. For given $k_1$ and $k_2$ (or the corresponding initial condition), can we find $c_1$ and $c_2$, such that $y_{b}(x) \rightarrow y_{b=0}(x)$ as $b\rightarrow 0$?
2. If not, what am I doing wrong? In particular, as I plot these functions for different values of $b$, I see a continuous transition between functions, but $b=0$ behaves like an anomaly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The continuity with respect to the parameter is under a fixed set of boundary conditions. Really these should be initial conditions. Boundary conditions can have discontinuities in certain cases, such as when a parameter in a linear problem with homogeneous boundary conditions passes through an eigenvalue.

For example, consider $y'+y=e^{kt},y(0)=0$, in a vicinity of $k=-1$. A particular solution for $k \neq -1$ is $\frac{e^{kt}}{1+k}$. The homogeneous solution is $Ce^{-t}$. The particular solution satisfies $y_p(0)=\frac{1}{1+k}$ so the solution to the IVP for $k \neq -1$ is

$$y=\frac{-e^{-t} + e^{kt}}{1+k}.$$

Sending $k \to -1$ in this expression (without having to know a particular solution for $k=-1$) gives the solution

$$y=te^{-t}$$

which is valid for $k=-1$.

A nice physical example of this is the problem

$$y''+y=\sin(kt),y(0)=0,y'(0)=0$$

with $k$ near $1$. This reveals that the unbounded amplitude oscillations of the problem $y''+y=\sin(t)$ arise not "discontinuously" but rather through arbitrarily large amplitude oscillations of $y''+y=\sin(kt)$ for $k$ near $1$.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to justify or resolve this issue? For example in my case, I'm using this for different values of $b$, and the solution function has to be continuous in $b$. Is there a (maybe-hack-ish) way to resolve this?

Comment: @Alt If your equation is $f(t,y(t),\dots,y^{(n)}(t);p)=0$, you're solving an IVP, and $f$ is a continuous function of $p$, then the solution is also a continuous function of $p$, except in special circumstances where you have to deal with "singular perturbation theory". Generally singular perturbation theory arises when the problem has no solution at all for a particular value $p^*$, and you are solving the problem for $p$ near $p^*$.

Comment: thanks! A silly question: So far I have been looking at second order linear ODE's  of the form : $a y'' + b y' + c y = u(t)$, where $u(t)$ is the step function. Is there any simple alternative that doesn't have the discontinuity in the IVP? (An oversimplified background, I use this as a reverse engineering approach to solving for functionals from a corresponding calculus of variation problem, so $a$,$b$ and $c$ are optimized as parameters of that problem. )

Comment: @Alt I don't understand the question. The problem you have is the problem you have...

Comment: I mean: what kind of changes (if any) can we apply to $ay″+by′+cy=1$, so that it would not have any singular points? (the coefficients do not need to stay scalar, but I want to keep the parametrization linear if possible. For example, if I set $b=0$, there won't be any singularities. Although the oscillation frequency will approach infinity as $a\rightarrow 0^+$), when $a,c\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @Alt What singular points are you troubled by? I don't see any except in the limit $a \to 0$.

Comment: $a\rightarrow 0$ is fine. My problem is with $b\rightarrow 0$, I was thinking if there are functions $q_i(x)~i\in\{0,1,2\}$, such that $aq_2(x)y'' + b q_1(x)y' + c q_0(x)y =1 $ is not singular as $b\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Alt I see no singularity at $b=0$. Are you thinking of $x \to \infty$? But then typically $x \to -\infty$ is a problem when $x \to \infty$ is not.